# How can I get a Search result from firebase xamarin....?

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, where-clause

My Firebase Node Is like this...

```js
Member
 -Kr4RLvm2ObnbnRvWXeb-wEr
    Age: "32"
    Email: "samaaa@uil.gl"
    IsActive: true
    ManagerId: "170809sam@uil.gl"
    MemberId: "170809sam@uil.gl"
    Name: "Samiufgfgl alfgfgam"
 -Kr4RLvmbnbn2ORvWXeb-wEr
    Age: "34"
    Email: "sasssm@uil.gl"
    IsActive: true
    ManagerId: "170809sam@uil.gl"
    MemberId: "170809sam@uil.gl"
    Name: "Samfgfgiul alam"
 -Kr4RLvm2OghghRvWXeb-wEr
    Age: "39"
    Email: "sacccm@uil.gl"
    IsActive: true
    ManagerId: "170809sam@uil.gl"
    MemberId: "170809sam@uil.gl"
    Name: "Samfffiul alam"
 -Kr4RLvm2ObvnbvnbvnRvWXeb-wEr
    Age: "66"
    Email: "sabbbm@uil.gl"
    IsActive: false
    ManagerId: "170809sam@uil.gl"
    MemberId: "170809sam@uil.gl"
    Name: "Samigggul alam"
```

I am able to retrive data from Xamarin in this way

```js
 var firebase = new FirebaseClient(url);
 var Current = await firebase.Child("Member").OnceAsync<Member>();
```

But I want data from fire base as 
select * from member where IsActive = true and Age > 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query more than on child in firebase, and plus that library you use cannot do that. If the platform you are working with is Mono.Android [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Database/) library will do .

And solution code below

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.GetReference("Member");
myRef.OrderByChild(mAge+"/IsActive").EqualTo(true).AddValueEventListener(this);
```

Also you need to change your database structure according to your needs in order for this solution to work like this age need to be like index

```
-Kr4RLvm2ObnbnRvWXeb-wEr
    Age: "32"
         Email: "samaaa@uil.gl"
         IsActive: true
         ManagerId: "170809sam@uil.gl"
         MemberId: "170809sam@uil.gl"
         Name: "Samiufgfgl alfgfgam"
 -Kr4RLvmbnbn2ORvWXeb-wEr
    Age: "34"
         Email: "sasssm@uil.gl"
         IsActive: true
         ManagerId: "170809sam@uil.gl"
         MemberId: "170809sam@uil.gl"
         Name: "Samfgfgiul alam"
    enter code here
```